# How do I set a default value for a named function argument?

Tags: fish

I have dug for an answer to this and [what I've found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81421/how-do-i-reference-a-variable-in-fish-shell-with-a-default-fallback) doesn't seem to work. If I run `weather "NYC"`, the echo'd line is "weather = NYC", however if I run `weather`, the echo'd line is "weather = ". How do I set a default value for `$location`?

```
function weather --argument location --description "Display weather information for a given location"
  set -q location; or set location "San Francisco, CA"
  echo "weather = $location"
  curl -H "Accept-Language: en" "wttr.in/$location?u"
end
```

**Update:**

I have been able to get the desired behavior with the following change but am still curious if the `set -q location; or set location "San Francisco, CA"` should work. It seems to on the command line, but not in the function.

```
if not test -n "$location"
  set location "Washington, DC"
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2645

The fishy solution of your workaround is this:

```
set -q location[1]
or set location "Washington, DC"
```

In practice your solution and the fishy one above are equivalent to simply testing whether the var is set.

Comment: This works for function argument too! If you omit the index from the query, your variable can be defined but with empty so you won't get your default value.